# SQL query to select percentage per Group

Tags: sql, database, group-by, teradata

I have a table named Grades which contains result of each year.
I want to select percentage of students who got more than 70 percent marks in each year.
Like e.g. for year 2012, 40 out of 100 got more than 70 percent. So the percentage for year 2012 is 40 %. 
I did it in sub query but I was wondering if it is possible without using sub query. 
I am using Teradata Version 6, which supports all basic sql queries.
My table schema is.

```
Table name: Grades<br>
Columns: Name, Marks, Year.
```

The best I could do is:

```
select (count(marks)/count(*))*100.0
from Grades
where marks > 70
Group by year;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the number of rows where marks > 70. Then divide it by the total number of rows in the table.

```
select 100.0 * sum(case when marks > 70 then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) 
from Grades
```

If you need the percentage for each year, you should `group by` the year column.

```
select year, 100.0 * sum(case when marks > 70 then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) 
from Grades
group by year
```

Comment: You are Life savor. Hats off to you. Stay blessed

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with average in one step.  If you want a value from 0 to 100:

```
select year,
       avg(case when marks > 70 then 100.0 else 0.0 end) as percentOver79
from Grades
group by year;
```

Comment: Yup that's another way to do it

Comment: It has the benefit of not accidentally doing integer division and getting the wrong answer.